# How to intercept SpringServletContainerInitializer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm running a `spring-boot` application on `tomcat`. When the app starts, the first class executed is `SpringServletContainerInitializer`.

How can to run some initialization **before** this class. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Initialization that does not depend on Spring? If so have you a `web.xml` file?

Comment: What do you need to initialize before that class?

Comment: I need to run some initialization before `log4j2` is initialized. As `SpringServletContainerInitializer` already makes use of logging, I must ensure some code is run before.

Comment: There is many way to achieve this, could you answer my question ?

Comment: Startup of logging is delayed to a certain point the startup doesn't use logging (it actually caches it and when started optionally logs the output).

Comment: @NicolasLabrot sorry, yes my custom initialization does not depend on spring, and I do not have a web.xml.

Comment: @M.Deinum no it's not. I put a breakpoint in `SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup()`, and before it is reached, the first log statements are created: `2016-05-13 10:45:14,672 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Cannot access RandomAccessFile {}) java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\${main:myparam}-my-application.txt`. I want to initialize the `main:myparam` based on a `vmargs` value, but the container of spring starts even before I can intercept it in any way.

Comment: My mistake I misread it for `SpringBootServletInitializer` however the `SpringServletContainerInitializer` is the first class executed and that doesn't use logging other then the servlet logging (`servletContext.log`). So there must be something else that is triggering this. Do you have files annotated with `@ServletListener` or something like that? Or other jars containing `ServletContainerInitializer`s?

Comment: No I don't have any `ServletListener` or similar, also no additional `Initializer`s. What I noticed: if I use `v2.4.1` the error log is not printed. But in `v2.5` it is.

Comment: You may have a look at [Log4j Servlet 3.0 and Newer Web Applications](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html), it may explain why you have a log message prior `SpringServletContainerInitializer`. But not why the error log is not printed in `v2.5`